# Azure Data Factory: Swapping LinkedServices conveniently

Tags: git, azure, azure-data-factory

I am currently trying to migrate from Azure SQL Databases as a linked service to Azure SQL for Postgres as the new linked service in Data Factory.

As far as I can tell, there is no convenient way to do this.

From the UI, you can change the linked service of each data set manually, but doing that for a few dozent will take time. I did it via the linked Git repository and renamed all the references for the datasets in the collaboration branch.

Now from Data Factory I cannot publish from the collaboration branch to the publish branch, because of "cannot publish due to invalid reference".

My next step now is to also rename all the references in the ARM templates, because I cannot create the automatically via the UI publish process.

Is there a better way to do this? Currently this seems highly manual, error prone and frustrating to do.

Comment: Manual changes in the code repository are probably the best way to do so. Why did you get "invalid reference"? Make sure you changed everything correctly, including all related datasets. If you're not sure - create a new Linked Service and dataset and then check their body (JSON files).
Also, for deployment, I prefer to use [#adftools](https://sqlplayer.net/adftools) (disclaimer: I'm the author), which allows you to deploy directly from code.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to adftools, will check it out! I am still not sure why I got the "invalid reference" error. I think I've renamed everything, disconnected and reconnected the repository, overwritten the live mode, deleted collaboration and publish branch and still cannot publish. I even deleted the LinkedService and created a new one. Any ideas?

Comment: Run [this command](https://github.com/SQLPlayer/azure.datafactory.tools#export-adf-code-to-armtemplate) from #adftools PowerShell module. It validates and generates ARM Template for you. All errors should be visible over there.

Comment: @KamilNowinski Thanks for the hint. Will check it out!

Comment: @KamilNowinski looks promising, thanks for coming back :-)